# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in : custom fields category

Tags: categories, custom-field, taxonomy

I have custom fields in my category. I'm using [this tutorial](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way) to add custom fields to my categories.

I'm trying to output one of the custom fields on my category.php template but I'm unable to do so. The code I added to my template is:

```
<?php 
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
$term_id = $current_term->term_id;
$saved_data = get_tax_meta($term_id,'text_field_id');
echo $saved_data;
?>
```

I have turned on debugging on and it shows error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /var/www/animedownloads.nu/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/category.php
>   on line 26

Here's the template code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Category pages
 *
 * Used to display archive-type pages for posts in a category.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

        <section id="primary" class="site-content">
                <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                        <header class="archive-header">
                                <h1 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
<?php
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
$term_id = $current_term->term_id;
$saved_data = get_tax_meta($term_id,'text_field_id');
echo $saved_data;
?>
                        <?php if ( category_description() ) : // Show an optional category description ?>
                                <div class="archive-meta"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </header><!-- .archive-header -->

                        <?php
                        /* Start the Loop */
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                                /* Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                                 * this in a child theme then include a file called called content-___.php
                                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                                 */
                                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                        endwhile;

                        twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' );
                        ?>

                <?php else : ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                </div><!-- #content -->
        </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the term was not found and `$current_term` returned as `false`:

```
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
$term_id = false === $current_term->term_id ? null : $current_term->term_id;
```

According to the docs, [`get_term_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) return values are

> Term Row (object or array) from database. Will return false if
>   $taxonomy does not exist or $term was not found. Othewise returns
>   object (by default) or array of fields depending on $output parameter.

Output the `$current_term` value and see if it is `false`:

```
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
var_dump( $current_term );
$term_id = $current_term->term_id;
```

Comment: Yes it returned the value false so how can i fix this?

Comment: Returning `false` means that the taxonomy does not exist or the term was not found. Double check if the term exists and the names that you are using are right.

Comment: The term should exist since I'm viewing the term page. Here is live version http://www.animedownloads.nu/category/mai-hime/ I really have no idea what code is wrong

Comment: I just noticed that you're calling `get_query_var` outside the loop, can you try to move it just after the line with `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` ?